# How to set image as background in valueBox() instead of color in shinyApp?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to set an image instead of background color "blue" in `valueBox()` in shinyApp. I don't know how to set an image to the background.

code:

```
valueBox(tags$p(HTML("Biometric"), style = "font-size: 100%", style = 
         "font-weight: bold"), subtitle = div(img(src = "metr.jpg", 
         height = "38", width = "80"), style = "text-align: right;"), 
         color = "blue", width = 3))
```

I want my `valueBox()` as the following image.

[image: looking like]

Can any one help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. Make sure you have placed the **metr.jpg** file inside 'www' directory inside your app folder. If not, the image will appear as a broken thumbnail.

I used your exact code, with the image file inside 'www' folder, the value box with just subtitles and adjusted image size. This is what I get.

[image: Sample valuebox with image]